# Maintaining server-wide dot files in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, etc

Let's say I'm administering an Ubuntu setup with multiple users for my organization.

We have a standard `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` with aliases, prompt settings, `PATH` declarations, etc... that we want all users to use. When a server is spun up it will be initialized with chef, which will be used to install these dotfiles on the system.

What's the best way to go about doing this? I see a few options, but they all have their downsides -

1. Install them under `/etc` (e.g. `/etc/profile`).**Pros:** Every user will read from this system-wide location. **Cons:** It overwrites any existing version of those flies that come pre-installed. We could always copy those into ours to begin with, but then we have to update and maintain them. May not be a problem depending on how often versions of Ubuntu end up changing the default dotfiles
2. Install them under `/etc`, but with another names (e.g. `/etc/bash_configs`) and then append a line to the stock `profile` and `bashrc` files to source our new files. **Pros:** It will also work and our settings will be sources. **Cons:** Seems really hack, and relies on programmatically appending a line to the end of the stock files to `source` our additional custom files.
3. Install them under `/etc/skel` so that every time a new user is created, those templates will get copied to their home directory. **Pros:** Each user will get their copy of the files correctly. **Cons:** What if we update the files, will they get updated in each individual directory? I'm guessing now. It would be better if there a way to symlink the files so all users point to the same files.

I might be over-complicating it, but it just feels like there has to be a cleaner way to do this that I'm missing. I'd be most interested in if there's a way to implement #3 with some sort of auto-update mechanism.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't have an auto update mechanism. That would delete any modifications the users might have made to their local versions.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would go for a mixture of 2 and 3. Place your modified files in `/etc/bash_config` or wherever. Then, modify the defaults in `/etc/skel` and have them source the files in `/etc/bash_config`.

This has some of the advantages of both 2 and 3:

- New users will have the right files;
- Any changes will immediately be propagated since the files are being sourced;
- This allows users to still modify their own dotfiles as they please.
- It does not involve editing the stock `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` files. This means that upgrades won't break your system.

Note that upgrades modifying the `/etc/skel` files could cause issues since that would mean your modifications were removed. That shouldn't be a big deal though.

As for its being hacky, well OK, it is. A little. Not too bad though, all you need is to run something like this once:

```
echo ". /path/to/my_bashrc/" >> /etc/skel/.bashrc
echo ". /path/to/my_profile/" >> /etc/skel/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place you modifications in `/etc/profile.d/` with `.sh` extension (e.g. `/etc/profile.d/MYCOMPANY.sh`). They will be called by `/etc/profile` automatically.

This way you can always update and all users will get those updates.